# google redirecting all search results to my homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, indexing

I have created an .htaccess file with the following code:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
rewriterule ^hie\/ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L] #5060c69211a2d
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/redirect.html
```

Google, for some reason, is redirecting all of my pages that come up in search results to my homepage.

I'm not sure why this is happening, bing and yahoo search results work fine. I realize that google has the link to my page as "example.com/siding/example.html" NOT "www.example.com/siding/example.html".

I have no idea why and no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your rule to:

```
rewriterule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```